# Upgrate postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, migration, upgrade

I'm going to upgrade postgresql from the version 9 to 11, I exported all the cluster using the command  `pg_dumpall -h localhost -p 5450  > /tmp/all.sql` I have installed postgresql 11 on my new server then I run the command `pg_restore -f all.sql --verbose 2>log.log` I'm wainting since 3 hours, the command haven't finished yet and there is no message inside the terminal, also the file log.log not found.

the size of all.sql is 65,1 Mo.

Did I make any mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `pg_restore` incorrectly. `-f` is *not* the input file, but the output file. `pg_restore` is waiting for the dump on standard input. On top of all that, `pg_restore` cannot be used to restore plain format dumps. You should run:

```bash
psql -d postgres -f all.sql
```

Comment: I run the command sudo -u postgres -i psql -f all.sql I get permission denied, I run chmod 777 all.sql but the same problem

Comment: "Permission error" is rather unspecific. Are you running both commands as the same operating system user?

Comment: I've fix the problem of permission, the database is created but when I run \dt I get Did not find any relations

Comment: Look at the log.

Comment: In the terminal I see the message tabled  created ...

Comment: in the terminal there is no error

Comment: Sigh. Did you look in `log.log`? Did you read the dump to see if it actually contains the data?

Comment: I've installed pgadmin, I've connected using the user postgres, I can see all the data, but when I connect using command line I can see the database but there isn't any table

Comment: I've installed pgadmin, I've connected using the user postgres, I can see all the data, but when I connect using command line I can see the database but there isn't any table

Comment: That's a different, unrelated problem. You will have to master the command line, connect to the correct database and set `search_path` appropriately.